# Можно ли реализовать будильник который сработал бы даже если девайс выключен?

Tags: java, android

Возможно ли это, если да то как? Я не смог найти примеров в интернете. У меня уже есть будильник, который работает после перезагрузки устройства но не в то время, когда девайс выключен.

Comment: правильный ответ, требуется аппаратная поддержка.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Некоторые android-устройства могут включаться самостоятельно по будильнику. Например, у Huawei это реализовано, но такую функцию должен реализовать производитель на аппаратном уровне и уровне драйверов системы.
Программно, на любом android-устройстве, сторонним разработчиком, реализовать такое невозможно.
Если производителем данная функция поддерживается, то устройство будет включаться по будильнику из полностью выключенного состояния без дополнительных действий со стороны стороннего разработчика, как и в случае с включенным устройством, если не поддерживается - повлиять на это сторонний разработчик никак не может.

Comment: Это просто означает, что этот Huawei не полностью выключается. Если выключить полностью - то работать не будет.

Comment: @Barmaley Полнее его выключить никак невозможно - это не спящий режим, а полное отключение, за будильником следит отдельная микросхема с собственной прошивкой - инфа в инете есть, я помню читал раньше, когда только купил. Тоже, в общем то, слабо верилось, что такое возможно на смарте.

Comment: а возможно ли просто заставить устройство включиться? программно.

Comment: @Dandewine Нет, это точно невозможно. В данном случае полностью справедлив ответ [Barmaley](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/430335/177345)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Ну известно, что в смарте есть несколько независимых от основного питания микросхем, например плата NFC в батарее - допускаю что есть такие же микросхемы у отдельных производителей

Comment: Разбираюсь немного в схемотехнике, существуют специализированные микросхемы часы с функцией будильника, потребляют они единицы микроампер. Когда сработает будильник, эта микросхема может включить телефон, подав сигнал на схему управления питанием. Поэтому мне странно что это сегодня преподносят как что-то особенное.

Answer (score 1):

Такое возможно при условие, что у вас есть доступ к аппаратной начинке, но это уже совсем другая история.

Answer (score 0):

Это не возможно. Если устройство выключено, то оно выключено.

Comment: это возможно, у меня Nexus One с 2.3 на борту, родной будильник это делать умеет, но позже производители стали выключать эту функцию, после версии 4.0

Comment: Точно? Я помню, когда у меня был кирпич-телефон, он даже после выключения из-за разрядки аккумулятора(!) включался чтобы разбудить.

Comment: да да, современный устройства это делать не умеют, где-то читал, что плохо сказывается на сроке жизни аккумулятора, но кирпичи умели однозначно. @АлексейСаровский

Comment: Мне кажется, что в принципе такая возможность существует, может быть недокументированная. Иначе сложно при необходимости встроить закладки в аппарат (они там должны быть, я уверен)

Answer (score 0):

Вы что тут с ума что ли сошли? Если телефон выключен, то нет питания, микросхемы не работают, ось не фунциклирует, программы никакие не работают - это невозможно.

А то что после перезагрузки работает будильник это в общем то несложно реализовать. Есть специальный бродкаст который рассылается по окончании перезапуска устройства `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`, для его ловли нужен пермишен: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>` - так что достаточно посадить на этот `BroadcastReceiver` и все.

Comment: Прямо передо мной лежит Huawei Honor, который отлично пробуждается из выключенного состояния по будильнику. Данная функция даже была заявлена при анонсе, как эксклюзивная для андроид-устройства, и это действительно почти так - читал, что у Lenovo тоже есть такие устройства. В общем то можно загуглить - при доброй воле производителя это возможно, часть смарта не выключается и следит за будильником, также низкоуровневый драйвер включает устройство, как в древних телефонах - технически ничего сложного.

Comment: это я уже реализовал, вопрос был возможно ли реализовать еще и активацию будильника когда он выключен. Пользователь выше, дал полезную информацию, на счет того, что все зависит от  производителя, повторюсь, на моем Nexus One Android 2.3, будильник срабатывает если телефон выключен, и даже села батарея.

Comment: Ну вопрос то был (судя по тегам) как реализовать в рамках Андроида. А то что вы описываете это к Андроиду никакого отношения не имеет. Это узкоспециальная фича реализованная в рамках отдельно взятого производителя на некой микросхеме на уровне устройства, но никак не оси

Comment: @pavlofff у меня Digma так делает.
А вы пробовали обесточить полностью (выключить, вынуть батарейку, потом вставить)?
Меня это заинтересовало!
Буду сегодня пробовать.